# Issue moving AI pong paddle in Java LWJGL/OpenGL

Tags: java, lwjgl

So I have a problem with my AI pong paddle. Right now, the AI is incredibly simple and dumb. All it does is move up and down at a continuous rate. I have no desire in perfecting this project, as it is really only to introduce me to LWJGL, so I will never create an intuitive AI for this system. However, I am having a problem with the paddle's AI. When the game starts, the paddle starts in the middle and goes straight up until it hits the ceiling. It hits the ceiling and then stops instead of going down until it can repeat the movement. I would like to know why the paddle just stops instead of continuing and following it's meant-to be paddle.

Startup Class: (This class is meant for starting the display and rendering, that includes the paddles.)

```
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

import com.evanklein.pong.entitity.CPUPlayer;
import com.evanklein.pong.entitity.Player;
import com.evanklein.pong.entitity.Ball;

public class Startup {

    // set up display
    public void start() {
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(600, 400));
            Display.setTitle("Pong");
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();
        GL11.glOrtho(0, 600, 400, 0, 1, -1);

        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            // render OpenGL here
            GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            // render player
            GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
            GL11.glVertex2d(player.startX, player.startY);
            GL11.glVertex2d(player.startX + 20, player.startY);
            GL11.glVertex2d(player.startX + 20, player.startY + 70);
            GL11.glVertex2d(player.startX, player.startY + 70);
            GL11.glEnd();

            // player controls
            if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_UP)) {
                player.moveUp();
            }
            if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_DOWN)) {
                player.moveDown();
            }

            // render AI
            GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
            GL11.glVertex2d(ai.startX, ai.startY);
            GL11.glVertex2d(ai.startX + 20, ai.startY);
            GL11.glVertex2d(ai.startX + 20, ai.startY + 70);
            GL11.glVertex2d(ai.startX, ai.startY + 70);
            GL11.glEnd();

            // set ai
            ai.move();

            // render Ball
            GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_LINE_LOOP);

            GL11.glEnd();

            Display.update();
            Display.sync(60);

        }

        Display.destroy();
    }

    // Let's start this beyotch up!
    Player player = new Player();
    CPUPlayer ai = new CPUPlayer();
    Ball ball = new Ball();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Startup().start();
    }
}
```

CPUPlayer class:

```
public class CPUPlayer {

    public int startX = 550; // starting positions (x, y), always locked
    public int startY = 150;

    private int moveSpeed = 2;
    public int score = 0; // init

    public void move() {
        startY -= moveSpeed;
        if (startY <= -10) {
            startY += moveSpeed; // switch directions
        } else if (startY >= 338) {
            startY -= moveSpeed;
        }
    }

}
```

My issue is simply that the paddle refuses to switch directions and instead sticks to the top of the display. Why does this happen, and what can I do to fix it? If you have any other questions or need any other specific details, please don't hesitate to let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in that when it reaches the top, you're simply telling it to move down once. After that, it still tries to move up and not down any more than once. To fix this, you need to have a 'direction' variable that tells it whether it's supposed to be moving up or down, and change the variable when the top/bottom is reached.

For example:

```
public class CPUPlayer {

    public int startX = 550;    // starting positions (x, y), always locked
    public int startY = 150;

    private int moveSpeed = 2;
    private boolean movingUp = true;
    public int score = 0;    // init

    public void move() {
        if(movingUp) {
            startY -= moveSpeed;
            if (startY <= -10)
                movingUp = false;    // switch directions
        } else {                     // Should be moving down
            startY += moveSpeed;
            if (startY >= 338)
                movingUp = true;    // switch directions
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice and clear, easy to understand, and organized. Thanks! Now to make the ball...

Answer (score 2):

You are always subtracting `moveSpeed`, then you are adding movespeed back on to switch directions.  This results in a net change of 0.

You'd need to add `moveSpeed*2` when `startY <= -10` in order to change directions. Your code will work like this:

```
public void move() {
    startY -= moveSpeed;
    if (startY <= -10) {
        startY += (moveSpeed*2); // switch directions
    } else if (startY >= 338) {
        startY -= moveSpeed;
    }
}
```

Viola!  Fixed!
However may I suggest a more sophisticated approach. Have the paddle operate in different modes like so:

```
boolean movingDown = false;
public void move() {
    int moveDir = movingDown?-moveSpeed:moveSpeed;
    startY += moveSpeed;
    if (startY <= -10 || startY>=338){
        movingDown = !movingDown;
    }
}
```

This will toggle whether a positive or negative increment is applied to your paddles position as the paddle moves too low, or too high.

Edit:
My code and Sharks code do essentially the same thing.  Mine uses the turnery operator, his uses an if/else statement.

Comment: Hi @William, yes our codes do the same thing, and yours is perhaps a nicer way of doing it, so I upvoted your answer seeing as we answered at the same time anyway. However, I think you need to correct your variables. You've used `movingUp` a couple of times by accident instead `movingDown`, I think ;)

Comment: Ah, good call, thanks @SharkofMirkwood. I'm disappointed I missed out on this, but I agree with the outcome.  I like your answer better.  Good job! The turnery is useful, but newer programmers dislike it. I've been trying to stop using it, single liners bother me.  Second time I've missed out on a question from this same user in 2 days lol.

Comment: Ah yes, I guess sometimes readability is more important. And better luck next time, heh.

Answer (score 1):

Your move method first deducts from startY then checks whether it should add or deduct further. In the case that it should add to startY, the value is simply returned to the original value prior to the move call. So startY never changes once it falls below -10.

I think your approach is flawed. You cannot accurately determine which direction the paddle is heading from only it's current position. Instead use a Boolean like "isMovingUp" and deduct/add to startY based on this. Change the Boolean when your bounds conditions are met.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
startY -= moveSpeed; // here, startY is -moveSpeed;


if (startY <= -10) {
        startY += moveSpeed; // switch directions (here, startY is 0) because
                             // -moveSpeed + moveSpeed = 0
} else if (startY >= 338) {
        startY -= moveSpeed ;
}
```

So adding `moveSpeed` to `startY` gives `-moveSpeed + moveSpeed = 0`.

To fix, add twice the amount of `moveSpeed`:

```
if (startY <= -10) {
        startY += 2 * moveSpeed; // switch directions                                  
} else if (startY >= 338) {
        startY -= 2 * moveSpeed ;
}
```

Comment: I understand why you think that -moveSpeed + moveSpeed = 0, but this does not solve the issue. The paddle now spazzes out at the bottom of the screen. Could this be an issue of something else?